# Pass NSString from one View Controller to another view not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

So I've looked a a bunch of stackoverflow answers and none of them seem to be helping. Maybe this is a special case? Here's my code so far:

So I'm assigning a string to a property that is declared within a another view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     FinalRead *readings = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     FinalReadingViewController *detailViewController = [[FinalReadingViewController alloc] init];

     detailViewController.lover = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", readings.a1];
     detailViewController.lover2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", readings.a2];
     detailViewController.monies = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",readings.a3];
     detailViewController.monies2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", readings.a4];
     detailViewController.healthy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", readings.a5];
     detailViewController.healthy2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",readings.a6];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

 }
```

and then in the next view controller I am then assigning the string to another property in the ANOTHER view controller:

```
- (IBAction)loveClicked:(id)sender {

    LoveDetailViewController *love = [[LoveDetailViewController alloc] init];


    NSString *stringLove1 = self.healthy;
    NSString *stringHealth2 = self.healthy2;

    stringLove1 = love.loverly;
    stringLove2 = love.loverly2;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController: love animated:YES];
}
```

And by the time that I get to that 3rd view controller the value comes up as (null). Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is not clear ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you make the assignments the wrong way around:

```
stringLove1 = love.loverly;
stringLove2 = love.loverly2;
```

should be

```
love.loverly = stringLove1;
love.loverly2 = stringLove2;
```

Comment: I really did not know that it mattered, but now I do. Do you think you'd be able to explain why if you don't mind? Thank you, btw.

Comment: @JohnSmith: You want to set the value `love.loverly` in the new view controller `love`, therefore `love.loverly = ...`. Your code `stringLove1 = love.loverly` overwrites the variable `stringLove1` with `love.loverly`, which is nil at that point.

Comment: I see. Thank you for that explanation. I hate to just do things mindlessly. Have a good one!

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```
love.loverly = stringLove1;
love.loverly2 = stringLove2;
```

Instead of

```
 stringLove1=love.loverly ;
 stringLove2=love.loverly2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you you mixed up order of assigment

```
stringLove1 = love.loverly;
stringLove2 = love.loverly2;
```

you should use

```
love.loverly = stringLove1;
love.loverly2 = stringLove2;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your loveClicked methods, it should be

```
love.loverly = stringLove1;
love.loverly2 = stringLove2;
```

Answer (score 0):

First Declare Property in SecondViewController
Like this

```
 @property NSString * str;
```

and then synthesize in SecondViewController.

```
@synthesize str;
```

then go to your FirstViewController declare one string in .h file.

```
NSString * str1;
```

and then pass like belo code..

```
 str1=@"abcd";
 SecondViewController * svc=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 svc.str=str1;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

then log the str in SecondViewController.m file

```
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

// Output is abcd..

follow this way